# How to pass dropdown list selected value in knockout function?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have to pass the dropdown selected value in knockout function. I have crated the razor syntax for that:

```
<div class="row">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FilterByType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "label" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FilterByType, new SelectList(Model.aspNetUser, "FilterByType", "FilterByName"), new { @class = "selectBox", @id = "aspnetUsersType", @data_bind = "event: {change: getData(0,'','',size,index,'')}" })
        <input type="hidden" id="filterByType" name="filterByType" value="">
    </div>
```

Following is my knockout function:

```
 self.getData = function (filterbytype, fromdaterange, todaterange, pageSize, page, searchText) {"some task"}
```

How do I pass the selected value in the getData? Right now I am passing 0 as a filterbytype.

Answer (score 0):

The objects can be passed from server to client using JSON, and binded to a property of type observableArray. Then bind this property to a html element using foreach binding. You can see an example here:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html

Answer (score 0):

Suppose are using this following code in ur HTML

```
<select data-bind="options: operations, value: self.selectedOperation">
```

Make sure that You must be using these variables as `ko.observable()` type

so ur JS code will look like this

```
  var self = this;
  self.selectedOperation = ko.observable("Option1"); // with self u can use more variables and here selectedOperation will be containing the choosen value you want and you can pass it wherever u want 
  var operations = ko.observableArray(["Option1", "Option2", "option3", "Opt4"]); // dropdown List
```

Now its up to you how you are going to use that variable..